# maven repositories and mirrors and command line options

Tags: maven, cmd, terminal, mirror

I'm having an issue where an external tool is being used to make a call which causes mvn to download a dependency on the fly.  This download however is calling the "central" enterprise artifactory repo rather than one of our normal artifactory repos and I'm trying to figure out how to make it mirror the enterprise repo to point to the appropriate repo.

All I've seen indicates I should be able to do this by setting the mirror in the settings.xml file, and I've passed the path to this settings file via the -s option.

But the mirror is still being ignored.

Is there something special about making a command to use a dependency via the commandline that bypasses mirrors?

Comment: No. If you give `mvn` a settings file with a correct mirror configuration, this mirror replaces everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the reason setting mirrors wasn't working was because the deployment mechanisms in place weren't actually setting the xml files as intended.  To get around it we added code to modify the .m2 folder to contain the xml files as part of the script run during deployment.